# PHP [Img] BBCode, but display only if the image is a real image?

Tags: php, regex, image, bbcode, verify

On my website, I have BBCode enabled on my forum, however, some of my users have been exploiting this, and have been making the source of the image a page that gives the user "Respect Points". I was wondering if there could be a way to check if the URL that is inside of the [ img ] tag is a real image, and not just a web page. I was thinking the "getimagesize" function could be useful here, but I can't find a proper way to check if it is a real image AND be able to parse it with regular expression afterwards. I'd prefer not just checking file extensions, because some images don't have file extensions on my website. Any insight on this?

Comment: You could use `getimagesize()`, but that wouldn't allow the inclusion of .tiff images or the like; it only supports JPG, PNG and I think BMP or GIF. You could see if the image's MIME type contains `image/`.

Comment: If you are planning on checking if it's a real image at every page load/refresh then that's the worst idea you could think of. Just add some sessionid/custom parameter check to your "Respect Points" script

Comment: Short answer: You can't. The host can check if the request is coming from you, and if so give you an image, while redirecting all others to vote. A way to fix this could be to not allow any actions via GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

getimagesize() is the way to go. It DOES support TIFF as well as just about every popular web image format. The only exception I can think of is SVG.

In addition to this, you should also set up a blacklist to prevent accessing certain pages.

```
<?php
function validURL($url){
    $bad = array("respect.php","website.com","etc");
    /* Check each array element to see if it is in the URL */
    foreach($bad as $fail){
        if(strpos($url,$fail) !== FALSE){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

if(validURL($url) && getimagesize($url) !== FALSE){
    // Valid image
} else {
    // Strip url
}
?>
```

The key here is that the **if** statement will short out if validURL() returns false. This will prevent getimagesize() from accessing any naughty URLs.